# Get ITextDocument for a RichTextBox in C#

Tags: c#, com, ole, richeditbox

This article...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4528/Use-IRichEditOle-from-C

... shows how to get IRichEditOle COM interface in C#. So far so good.

I'm stuck writing the code to get the ITextDocument interface in C#.

(btw, I need it to access Undo(tomSuspend,NULL) so if a workaround exist, it would be just as welcome)

Answer (score 8):

I found most of the solution buried in the comments of the article I linked to above.

For those interested, this is what a complete solution would look like:

```
[ComImport]
[InterfaceType( ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown )]
[Guid( "00020D00-0000-0000-c000-000000000046" )]
public interface IRichEditOle
{
    int GetClientSite( IntPtr lplpolesite );
    int GetObjectCount();
    int GetLinkCount();
    int GetObject( int iob, REOBJECT lpreobject, [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.U4 )] GetObjectOptions flags );
    int InsertObject( REOBJECT lpreobject );
    int ConvertObject( int iob, CLSID rclsidNew, string lpstrUserTypeNew );
    int ActivateAs( CLSID rclsid, CLSID rclsidAs );
    int SetHostNames( string lpstrContainerApp, string lpstrContainerObj );
    int SetLinkAvailable( int iob, int fAvailable );
    int SetDvaspect( int iob, uint dvaspect );
    int HandsOffStorage( int iob );
    int SaveCompleted( int iob, IntPtr lpstg );
    int InPlaceDeactivate();
    int ContextSensitiveHelp( int fEnterMode );
    //int GetClipboardData(CHARRANGE FAR * lpchrg, uint reco, IntPtr lplpdataobj);
    //int ImportDataObject(IntPtr lpdataobj, CLIPFORMAT cf, HGLOBAL hMetaPict);
}

public enum GetObjectOptions
{
    REO_GETOBJ_NO_INTERFACES    = 0x00000000,
    REO_GETOBJ_POLEOBJ          = 0x00000001,
    REO_GETOBJ_PSTG             = 0x00000002,
    REO_GETOBJ_POLESITE         = 0x00000004,
    REO_GETOBJ_ALL_INTERFACES   = 0x00000007,
}

[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
public struct CLSID
{
    public int      a;
    public short    b;
    public short    c;
    public byte     d;
    public byte     e;
    public byte     f;
    public byte     g;
    public byte     h;
    public byte     i;
    public byte     j;
    public byte     k;
}

[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
public struct SIZEL
{
    public int  x;
    public int  y;
}

[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
public class REOBJECT
{
    public REOBJECT()
    {
    }

    public int      cbStruct    = Marshal.SizeOf( typeof( REOBJECT ) );     // Size of structure
    public int      cp          = 0;                                        // Character position of object
    public CLSID    clsid       = new CLSID();                              // Class ID of object
    public IntPtr   poleobj     = IntPtr.Zero;                              // OLE object interface
    public IntPtr   pstg        = IntPtr.Zero;                              // Associated storage interface
    public IntPtr   polesite    = IntPtr.Zero;                              // Associated client site interface
    public SIZEL    sizel       = new SIZEL();                              // Size of object (may be 0,0)
    public uint     dvaspect    = 0;                                        // Display aspect to use
    public uint     dwFlags     = 0;                                        // Object status flags
    public uint     dwUser      = 0;                                        // Dword for user's use
}

public class API
{
    [DllImport( "User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto )]
    public static extern int SendMessage( IntPtr hWnd, int message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam );
}

public class Messages
{
    public const int    WM_USER             = 0x0400;
    public const int    EM_GETOLEINTERFACE  = WM_USER + 60;
}


protected IRichEditOle  IRichEditOleValue   = null;
protected IntPtr        IRichEditOlePtr     = IntPtr.Zero;

[ComImport]
[InterfaceType( ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown )]
[Guid( "8CC497C0-A1DF-11ce-8098-00AA0047BE5D" )]
public interface ITextDocument
{
// IDispath methods (We never use them)
int GetIDsOfNames( Guid riid, IntPtr rgszNames, uint cNames, uint lcid, ref int rgDispId );
int GetTypeInfo( uint iTInfo, uint lcid, IntPtr ppTInfo );
int GetTypeInfoCount( ref uint pctinfo );
int Invoke( uint dispIdMember, Guid riid, uint lcid, uint wFlags, IntPtr pDispParams, IntPtr pvarResult, IntPtr pExcepInfo, ref uint puArgErr );

// ITextDocument methods
int GetName( /* [retval][out] BSTR* */ [In, Out, MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.BStr )] ref string pName );
int GetSelection( /* [retval][out] ITextSelection** */ IntPtr ppSel );
int GetStoryCount( /* [retval][out] */ ref int pCount );
int GetStoryRanges( /* [retval][out] ITextStoryRanges** */ IntPtr ppStories );
int GetSaved( /* [retval][out] */ ref int pValue );
int SetSaved( /* [in] */ int Value );
int GetDefaultTabStop( /* [retval][out] */ ref float pValue );
int SetDefaultTabStop( /* [in] */ float Value );
int New();
int Open( /* [in] VARIANT **/ IntPtr pVar, /* [in] */ int Flags, /* [in] */ int CodePage );
int Save( /* [in] VARIANT * */ IntPtr pVar, /* [in] */ int Flags, /* [in] */ int CodePage );
int Freeze( /* [retval][out] */ ref int pCount );
int Unfreeze( /* [retval][out] */ ref int pCount );
int BeginEditCollection();
int EndEditCollection();
int Undo( /* [in] */ int Count, /* [retval][out] */ ref IntPtr prop );
int Redo( /* [in] */ int Count, /* [retval][out] */ ref IntPtr prop );
int Range( /* [in] */ int cp1, /* [in] */ int cp2, /* [retval][out] ITextRange** */ IntPtr ppRange );
int RangeFromPoint( /* [in] */ int x, /* [in] */ int y, /* [retval][out] ITextRange** */ IntPtr ppRange );
}

public class TomConstants
{
public const int    tomSuspend  = -9999995;
public const int    tomResume   = -9999994;
}

protected ITextDocument ITextDocumentValue  = null;
protected IntPtr        ITextDocumentPtr    = IntPtr.Zero;
```

then

```
public IRichEditOle GetRichEditOleInterface()
{
    if( this.IRichEditOleValue == null )
    {
        // Allocate the ptr that EM_GETOLEINTERFACE will fill in
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem( Marshal.SizeOf( typeof( IntPtr ) ) );  // Alloc the ptr.
        Marshal.WriteIntPtr( ptr, IntPtr.Zero );                                    // Clear it.
        try
        {
            if( 0 != API.SendMessage( this.Handle, Messages.EM_GETOLEINTERFACE, IntPtr.Zero, ptr ) )
            {
                // Read the returned pointer
                IntPtr pRichEdit = Marshal.ReadIntPtr( ptr );
                try
                {
                    if( pRichEdit != IntPtr.Zero )
                    {
                        // Query for the IRichEditOle interface
                        Guid guid = new Guid( "00020D00-0000-0000-c000-000000000046" );
                        Marshal.QueryInterface( pRichEdit, ref guid, out this.IRichEditOlePtr );

                        // Wrap it in the C# interface for IRichEditOle
                        this.IRichEditOleValue = (IRichEditOle)Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown( this.IRichEditOlePtr, typeof( IRichEditOle ) );

                        if( this.IRichEditOleValue == null )
                        {
                            throw new Exception( "Failed to get the object wrapper for the IRichEditOle interface." );
                        }

                        // IID_ITextDocument
                        guid = new Guid( "8CC497C0-A1DF-11CE-8098-00AA0047BE5D" );
                        Marshal.QueryInterface( pRichEdit, ref guid, out this.ITextDocumentPtr );

                        // Wrap it in the C# interface for IRichEditOle
                        this.ITextDocumentValue = (ITextDocument)Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown( this.ITextDocumentPtr, typeof( ITextDocument ) );

                        if( this.ITextDocumentValue == null )
                        {
                            throw new Exception( "Failed to get the object wrapper for the ITextDocument interface." );
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception( "Failed to get the pointer." );
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    Marshal.Release( pRichEdit );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception( "EM_GETOLEINTERFACE failed." );
            }
        }
        catch( Exception err )
        {
            Trace.WriteLine( err.ToString() );
            this.ReleaseRichEditOleInterface();
        }
        finally
        {
            // Free the ptr memory
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem( ptr );
        }
    }

    return this.IRichEditOleValue;
}

public void ReleaseRichEditOleInterface()
{
    if( this.IRichEditOlePtr != IntPtr.Zero )
    {
        Marshal.Release( this.IRichEditOlePtr );
    }

    this.IRichEditOlePtr    = IntPtr.Zero;
    this.IRichEditOleValue  = null;
}
```

Calls to suspend/resume undo could look like:

```
public void EnableUndo( bool enable )
{
    if( IRichEditOleValue == null )
    {
        GetRichEditOleInterface();
    }

    IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;

    ITextDocumentValue.Undo( ( enable == true ) ? TomConstants.tomResume : TomConstants.tomSuspend, ptr );
}
```

The credit for this solution goes to John Fisher for writing the original article and to Chris Woodall for providing the ITextDocument interface code in the comments. All errors are mine.

Comment: this.ReleaseRichEditOleInterface() in the catch is undefined?

Comment: Yep. Forgot to include it. Sorry about that. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm working on a project and I dropped this code in and it worked first time.

Comment: No worries. Remember call dispose.

Comment: I wrapped up the Lara's code here: [Source](https://github.com/Isaac44/SingleCodes/blob/master/CSharp/RichOLE.cs); [usage example](https://github.com/Isaac44/SingleCodes/blob/master/CSharp/RichOLE_Example.cs)